# Возникает ошибка OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Вот возникает следующая ошибка при выполнении программы. Как мне ее избежать, помогите пожалуйста?

```
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 51916812 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 39MB until OOM"
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
                      Process: com.example.work, PID: 25823
                      java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51916812 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 39MB until OOM
                          at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:650)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:626)
                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:664)
                          at com.example.work.MainStudent$1.run(MainStudent.java:115)
                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
    W/AndroidRuntime: finished raiseRlimit, rlim_cur:4096  rlim_max:4096


 String sql2 = "SELECT photo1,photo2,photo3 FROM post where email ="+"'"+Login.User+"'";
                try {
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        if(rs.getBlob("photo1") != null) {
                            Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("photo1");
                            binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(1, imageBlob.length());
                            postImage.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(binaryStream));
                        }
                        else{
                            postImage.add(null);
                        }
                        if(rs.getBlob("photo2") != null) {
                            Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("photo2");
                            binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(1, imageBlob.length());
                            postImage.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(binaryStream));

                        }
                        else {
                            postImage.add(null);
                        }
                        if(rs.getBlob("photo3") != null) {
                            Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("photo3");
                            binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(1, imageBlob.length());
                            postImage.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(binaryStream));

                        }
                        else {
                            postImage.add(null);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Наверное вы пытаетесь отображать очень больше картинки. Без деталей большего сказать нельзя. Попробуйте уменьшить картинки.

Comment: Как уменшить BitmapFactory.decodeStream(binaryStream) размер програмно?

Comment: android:largeHeap="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте уменьшить потребление памяти путём ухудшения качества по цвету и размеру:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);
```

Comment: Ну, а если в списке будет много изображений?

Comment: @user221117, тогда ничего не поможет) Всё отображаемое загружается в оперативную память и если там много всего - будет лагать и падать.

Comment: Перед загрузкой проверяйте размер картинки без загрузки. С помощью optionsNewBitmap.inJustDecodeBounds = true; Если большая слишком, то меняйте размер с помощью options.inSampleSizе, только потом загружайте.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, уменьшить качество картинок в базе.

Во-вторых, вынести картинки в отдельную таблицу, а в списке писем оставить id изображения. Когда нужны будут картинки - селектить их не всей пачкой сразу, а по одной, обрезая размер до вменяемого, как уже советовали в комментариях, если они все же больше разрешения экрана/размеров вьюшке, в которой будет отображаться.

В-третьих, если первых двух пунктов не хватит, добавить в манифест в тег  атрибут android:largeHeap="true". Он увеличит максимальное количество оперативной памяти для приложения

В-четвертых, повесить на поток "перехватчик неперхваченых исключений", т.к. OutOfMemory не ловится catch-ем. Реализовать Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler и повесить его на основной поток

```
Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
```

Тогда хотя бы можно среагировать и показать пользователю сообщение об ошибке, а не просто умереть

В-пятых, лучше не работать с картинками  в основном потоке. Этот процесс может быть болезненным. Рекомендую взять библиотеку для загрузки изображений, например Picasso. Ее использование вынесет загрузки картинок в отдельный поток, она обработает OutOfMemory и любую другую ошибку при загрузке так, что программа продолжит работать, просто вместо нужной картинки подставят картинку ошибки. В общем, полезная штука :)